# Placing an image in the middle of the label in Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have the following `Kivy` language file, which should mimic a dialer app. Also in the middle underneath the digits it should display an icon (*red rectangle*). However it seems that in my implementation the `parent`, `self` and `root` objects all have the same properties. What's wrong in my code? Is there a better way to do it?

```
# File name: dialer.kv 
#:kivy 1.9.0
<Button>:
    color: .8,.9,0,.65
    font_size: 32

<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: .40
        Label:            
            text: '12345678901231234567890'
            size: self.texture_size
            text_size: root.width, None
            font_size: 44
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.parent.center_x - self.width / 2, self.parent.center_y - self.height / 2
                    source: 'bg.png'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 4
        size_hint_y: .50
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: '1'
        Button:
            text: '2'
        Button:
            text: '3'
        Button:
            text: '4'
        Button:
            text: '5'
        Button:
            text: '6'
        Button:
            text: '7'
        Button:
            text: '8'
        Button:
            text: '9'
        Button:
            text: '*'
        Button:
            text: '0'
        Button:
            text: '#'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint_y: .10
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: 'Clear'
        Button:
            text: 'Dial'
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# File name: main.py

import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class DialerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    DialerApp().run()
```

[image: Dialer app]

Answer (score 2):

`self` variable you're using inside the canvas instructions is referencing to enclosing widget class (in this case it's a label), not a `VertexInstruction` like `Rectangle`. In your code `self.parent.center_x` is in fact the center of `GridLayout` and the `self.width` is the label width. To place your image in the middle of the label you can calculate the position manually:

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: .40
        Label:            
            # ...

            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.center_x - 50, self.center_y - 50 # default size is 100x100       
                    source: 'test.png' 

    # ...
```

You can also use Image widget as follows:

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: .40
        Label:            
            # ...

            Image:
                center: self.parent.center
                source: 'test.png'               

    # ...
```

`Image` is a Widget so now `self` refers to it and `self.parent` refers to the `Label` and we can use the `center` attribute to calculate the position automatically.