# Any suggestions for loading an Image from a file dialog?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building GUI for my app and I'm trying to load an image from file dialog.
Does somebody has any suggestions? This is my first Kivy application and sometimes I can't fully understand the documentation. I've tried multiple ways and the best result I got was an image at the bottom left of the screen.

I've tried the solution from [Placing an image in the middle of the label in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413521/placing-an-image-in-the-middle-of-the-label-in-kivy), but that didn't solve my problem.

Part of my .kv file:

```
<RunDemoScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text:"Test"


        Button:
            text:"File"
            on_press: root.file_dialog()

        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

Part of my python code:

```
class RunDemoScreen(Screen):

    def file_dialog(self):
        Tk().withdraw()
        self.filename = askopenfilename()
        print(self.filename)
```

Everything in this code works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using an `Image` widget?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes, I tried and it works but only when I use pos. With pos_hint it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to create an Image widget and then change the source of the image to your self.filename variable using the id you'd assign to it

in your .kv:

```
Image:
    id: imageWidget
    source: ''
    opacity: 0 # to make it completely invisible till your add a source file
```

in your .py:

```
def file_dialog(self):
    Tk().withdraw()
    self.filename = askopenfilename()
    imageWid = self.ids['imageWidget']
    imageWid.source = self.filename
    imageWid.opacity= 1 # to make it visible
```

Comment: I hope you find this helpful. If you do, vote the answer and accept it by clicking on the Check sign.

Comment: Thank you, @eyllanes! This solved my problem, I accepted the answer, but couldn't vote, because I don't have enought reputation.

Comment: @M.Momchilov I have not answered your question, I have only edited the question :-)